# Getting a "String or binary data would be truncated" error not sure why

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2017 with SQL Server 2016 Express, and the following method:

```
protected void subFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String regPattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{8}$";
    String regPattern2 = "^\\d{11}$";


    if (Regex.IsMatch(txtAwbNum.Text, regPattern) || Regex.IsMatch(txtAwbNum.Text, regPattern2))
    {
        String AwbNum = txtAwbNum.Text;
        int doorNum = Convert.ToInt16(ddlDoorNum.SelectedValue);
        String driverName = txtDriverName.Text;
        String carrier = txtCarrier.Text;
        int pieces = Convert.ToInt32(txtPieces.Text);
        SqlDecimal GrossWt = SqlDecimal.Parse(txtGrossWt.Text);
        SqlDecimal ChargeWt = SqlDecimal.Parse(txtChargeableWt.Text);
        String flightNum = ddlFlightNum.ToString();
        SqlDateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
        String destination = txtDestination.Text;
        String shipper = txtShipper.Text;
        Boolean dgCheck = chkDgCheck.Checked;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        String dropoffId = DateTime.Today.ToString();


        String queryString = "INSERT INTO ExpAwbs (idExpAwbs, Pieces, GrossWt, ChargeWt, Flight, FlightDate, Shipper, Destination, dgCheck) values (@AwbNum, @pieces, @GrossWt, @ChargeWt, @flightNum, @date, @shipper, @destination, @dgCheck);";
        String queryString2 = "INSERT INTO Dropoff (idDropoff, DoorNum, Carrier, DriverName, datetime) values (@dropoffID, @doorNum, @carrier, @driverName, @today);";

        String connectionString = "Data Source=PCNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TASdb;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(queryString2, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AwbNum", AwbNum);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pieces", pieces);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrossWt", GrossWt);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeWt", ChargeWt);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flightNum", flightNum);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", destination);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipper", shipper);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dgCheck", dgCheck);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doorNum", doorNum);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carrier", carrier);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driverName", driverName);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dropoffId", dropoffId);

        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteReader();
        command.Connection.Close();

        command2.Connection.Open();
        command2.ExecuteScalar();
        command2.Connection.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid AWB. Please check again and re-submit.");
    }

}
```

When I run this, I get a "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated." I don't understand why that could be. I have made sure that all of the fields are less than or equal to the allotted size in the database. The only ones I had question about were the GrossWt and ChargeWt because in the database their datatype is Decimal(6, 1), but I don't think that's the problem because I tried taking them out, and that didn't change anything. Below is the database table designs for the related tables (FlightDate column has actually been updated to be a datetime datatype):

[image: ExpAwbs database table]

[image: Dropoff database table]

Comment: As youve stated, this generally occurs when you are inserting more data than a field can hold. Eg, Origin is longer than 3 characters. Your best bet is to use profiler to see the statement being sent to the database and then replay it yourself.

Comment: You can find tens of QA about this error. Please figure it out by searching it

Comment: Why are you doing `ExecuteScalar()` and `ExecuteReader()`? You should be using `ExecuteNonQuery()` for both of those commands (and inside a transaction, ideally) from what I can see.

Comment: @AndrewHarris I didn't know about the profiler. Thanks for the tip, that helped me figure out the issue.

Comment: @JohnEblin then please up vote the comment and post back what the problem was.